# Firebase User Authentication Panel Search Limitation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

The user list was great on console of Firebase; until some kind of update affected the search of all authenticated users. It was really easy to search by typing in search field '@' character to see all authenticated user. Unfortunately Firebase is now only allowed to search by email or uid. Is there a way to find all authenticated users without using BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. We needed to disable partial searches across the user table because in some instances we were seeing very high latency times for projects with large numbers of users. We are working on optimizations for this and will update the tab when we're able to bring it back.

I apologize for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thank you. I hope you'll fix that problem soon.